# Kotlin multiple interface delegation

Tags: function, kotlin, delegates

How do I efficiently write delegation in Kotlin?

I have the following problem:

I am exposing an interface to my client. Let's call it `ExternalInterface`.

```kotlin
interface ExternalInterface {
  fun fun1()
  fun fun2()
  fun fun3()
  fun fun4()
}
```

I am implementing this in my package without delegation as follows:

```kotlin
class Impl(
   obj1: InternalInterface1,
   obj2: InternalInterface2
): ExternalInterface {
     override fun fun1() = obj1.fun1()
     override fun fun2() = obj1.fun2()
     override fun fun3() = obj2.fun3()
     override fun fun4() = obj2.fun4()
}
```

This is because it is easier to group the functions by some internal classifications, so that I can have something as follows:

```kotlin
class RelatedStuff : InternalInterface1 {
  ....
}

class OtherRelatedStuff : InternalInterface2 {
  ....
}
```

where my internal interfaces are just breakdowns of the externalInterface:

```
interface InternalInterface1 {
   fun fun1()
   fun fun2()
}

interface InternalInterface2 {
   fun fun3()
   fun fun4()
}
```

Is it possible to use delegates here in a way that my client can still rely on `ExternalInterface` but I can clean up the `Impl` class code?

Effectively, I think I want to reach somewhere like:

```
class Impl(
   obj1: InternalInterface1,
   obj2: InternalInterface2
): InternalInterface1 by obj1, InternalInterface2 by obj2
```

but also want it to implement `ExternalInterface`.

Comment: What's stopping you from simply tacking `, ExternalInterface` onto the interfaces this class is implementing?

Comment: @Tenfour04, hmm, so you mean I add that and because this class now has two interfaces with the same method, both of them are handled because of the single definition? I mean, it works, just not sure, that having a single implementation method for two interface APIs is a good practice.

Comment: Since it already implements all the method signatures required by ExternalInterface, it satisfies that interface as well if you declare it. Personally, I tend to avoid overlapping signatures between interface methods because I think it is likely to be error prone. But in this case your other interfaces are internal and you can document them as existing purely for delegation of a portion of ExternalInterface.

Comment: If they didn't have to be internal, you could make ExternalInterface extend both of the other interfaces to avoid the ambiguity of overlapping method signatures.

Comment: @Tenfour04, true, in my case I can't put them external because it has variables of a dependency that the external interface package does not have.

Comment: How is that possible if they have the same method signatures as the external interface?

Comment: The internal interfaces also have some `var`s and `val`s.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create a 3rd interface (`Facade` in my example) and make `Impl` implement it as well:

```kotlin
interface InternalInterface1 {
   fun fun1()
   fun fun2()
}

interface InternalInterface2 {
   fun fun3()
   fun fun4()
}

interface Facade : InternalInterface1, InternalInterface2

class Impl(
   obj1: InternalInterface1,
   obj2: InternalInterface2
): InternalInterface1 by obj1, InternalInterface2 by obj2, Facade
```

Although this design seems a bit weird to me. What I usually do is that I have a bunch of external interfaces (I call them APIs) and some internal interfaces that extend the API interfaces:

```kotlin
interface ExternalInterface1 {
    fun fun1()
}

interface ExternalInterface2 {
    fun fun2()
}

interface InternalInterface1 : ExternalInterface1 {
    fun fun3()
}

interface InternalInterface1 : ExternalInterface2 {
    fun fun4()
}

interface ExternalAPI: ExternalInterface1, ExternalInterface2

interface InternalAPI: InternalInterface1, InternalInterface2

class Impl: InternalAPI {
    obj1: InternalInterface1,
    obj2: InternalInterface2
}: InternalAPI, InternalInterface1 by obj1, InternalInterface2 by obj2
```

This way your external interface is pristine, but you can still have some internals using your `InternalAPI`. Then you can add something like this:

```kotlin
/**
 * Exposes the internal API of [ExternalAPI]. Note that all methods exposed this
 * way are subject to change!
 */
fun asInternal(): InternalAPI = this
```

and everyone is happy.